# Inheritance: Giving derived& as arg to function expecting base&

Tags: c++, inheritance

Consider this example code:

```
#include <iostream>

class base {
    public:
    base() {
        std::cout << "base constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    base(const base & source) {
        std::cout << "base copy-constructed" << std::endl;
    }
};

class derived : public base {
    public:
    derived() {
        std::cout << "derived constructed" << std::endl;
    }
    derived(const derived &) = delete;
    derived(const base & source) : base(source) {
        std::cout << "derived copy-constructed from base" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    derived a;
    base b(a);
    derived c(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is it that the call to `base::base(const base &)` is okay, but the call to `derived::derived(const base &)` is not?  Both expect a base reference, and both are given a derived reference.  It's my understanding that derived 'is a' base.

Why does the compiler insist on using `derived::derived(const derived &)` when it has no problem using `base::base(const base &)` when supplied with a reference to an object of type derived?

Comment: Where does the compiler complain (and what's the exact message)? **edit**: [The error I got](http://ideone.com/fylVh) was `prog.cpp:18:5: error: deleted function 'derived::derived(const derived&)' prog.cpp:27:16: error: used here`

Comment: Apparently 'deleting' one of the default things doesn't have the effect of actually deleting it exactly. Some grisly ghoulish vestige of  the once proud copy constructor is left lying around to pop up and tell you in a sepulchral voice "I'm deeeeaaaaaad!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently 'deleting' one of the default things doesn't have the effect of actually deleting it exactly. Some grisly ghoulish vestige of the once proud default copy constructor is left lying around to pop up and tell you in a sepulchral voice "*I'm deeeeaaaaaad!*".

This is not an altogether surprising fact to me, though I was unaware of it in specific before you asked this question. I could not quote you the relevant section of the standard (and I'm certain that the relevant section makes no mention of ghouls, though it should). And I'm also fairly certain there is some reason why this is the case that turns out to be perfectly sensible once you follow some incredibly convoluted story about some horrible case that would work in a terrible way if it weren't.

And, unfortunately for you, if there's something lying around that's a better match than a conversion to a base class, it's what will be used.  For example, in this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
};

class B {
 public:
   void foo(const A &) { ::std::cerr << "B::foo(const A &) called!\n"; }
   void foo(const B &) { ::std::cerr << "B::foo(const B &) called!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    A &ar = b;
    b.foo(b);
    b.foo(ar);
};
```

will result in this output:

```
B::foo(const B &) called!
B::foo(const A &) called!
```

Which is exactly as you'd expect. The compiler does not treat the situation as ambiguous. And if you made `void foo(const B &)` into a *private* or *protected* member, then the compiler would still match it in preference to the other, and tell you you tried to access something that had an access specifier that said you couldn't.

Think of setting something to be 'deleted' as simply declaring it with a special access specifier that's even more restricted than *private*.

Comment: Regarding the first paragraph: In the expression `derived(derived const&) = deleted;`, there are two parts, a declaration: `derived(derived const&)` and a definition `= deleted`. While this might not be obvious the important difference is that a `delete`d function will still take part of overload resolution (where only declarations are considered), but if/when it is chosen as the best candidate the compiler will fail telling you that it is *deleted*. The whole 8.4.3 section is clear in that this is a *definition*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: So my characterization of something having a definition of `= deleted` being sort of like it has a access specifier that's even more exclusive than `private` isn't totally inaccurate then? I don't generally read standards documents most of the time because I find that the careful language they're written in frequently obscures the underlying pattern that underlies the logic of why something is the way it is.

Comment: Well, I would not really call it that way, but to some extent you are right, it is a tag telling the compiler *complain when used*. The reason I would not compare with access specifiers is that access specifiers select a subset of the code from which the member can be accessed, but in this case there is no subset (other than the empty set)

Answer (score 2):

```
derived a; 
derived c(a);
```

You have explicitly `deleted` the copy constructor. That means that the second line above will fail to compile. The difference with the `base` case is that in the base case there is no constructor of `base` declared that takes a `derived&`, so conversions are applied.

But on the case of `derived` there **is** such a function, it is declared and deleted. Overload resolution will find both `derived(derived const &)` and `derived(base const &)` as both are declared, and will pick the first as the best match. It will then find that it is deleted and complain.

If you want to use the other constructor with a `derived` object you have to explicitly cast:

```
derived c( static_cast<base&>(a) );
```

In this case, the best overload becomes `derived( base const& )` and the code will compile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and say it's because the signature of `derived c(a);` exactly matches the signature of the function you deleted. C++ will try to avoid casts/promotions/conversions if possible and will prefer the closest match. Casting `a` to the proper type (`base`) should fix it so that it stops matching the signature of the deleted function and starts matching the signature of the other constructor.